# How to find the power series representation of $\frac{x-1}{x+2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

The question is what is the power series representation of $\frac{x-1}{x+2}$. This was my initial solution.

$$\frac{x-1}{x+2} = (x-1)\left(\frac{1}{x+2}\right) = \frac{x-1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{1-(-\frac{x}{2})}\right) = \frac{x-1}{2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^n $$

Now the solution my textbook has is $$-\frac{1}{2} - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n3x^n}{2^{n+1}}$$

The question is, how do we get that? I see if you take the first two terms of my answer you get $-\frac{1}{2}$ as a constant outside the series notation. What I then have is $$-\frac{1}{2} + (x-1)\sum_{n=2}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{x^n}{2^{n+1}}$$

How do I get the book's answer? I don't see where to go from here.

Comment: An idea I just had was to make a substitution with y = x-1 and then I see how a 3 could appear but idk if that would work. i'll try tho

Comment: carefully write what happens with $x$ times your sum from $n=2.$  The importance is that you need to take that, with the shifted exponents,  and write that over as a sum with exponent $n.$  Also work out what $n$ begins with for this shifted sum...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple: they rewrote  the fraction as:
$$\frac{x-1}{x+2}=\frac{(x+2)-3}{x+2}=1-\frac{3}{x+2}=1-\frac32\,\frac1{1+\cfrac x2}$$
and used the expansion of $\:\dfrac1{1+u}$.